# How to to invoke an @DELETE web service in REST using ajax call?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I am working on web api project wherein I have to write method to delete an account.
I have created a controller called RemoveAccount where I have written my Delete account method.
Following is the code.

```
        public RemoveAccountRes Delete(RemoveAccountModel objRemove, string function = "")
    {
        RemoveAccountRes objModel = new RemoveAccountRes();
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            User user = null;
            try
            {
                user = UserHelper.GetLoggedInUser(Convert.ToString(user.UserGuid));
                if (user == null || objRemove.User == null)
                {
                    objModel.ErrorMessage = "User Not Valid";
                    objModel.ErrorCode = 403;
                    objModel.Success = false;

                    return objModel;
                }
                if (function == "delete")
                {
                    UserRepository.Delete(objRemove.User.UserId);
                    UserHelper.LogOutUser();
                    objModel.ErrorMessage = "Account is Deleted";
                    objModel.ErrorCode = 200;
                    objModel.UserGuid = Convert.ToString(user.UserGuid);
                    objModel.Success = true;
               }
            }
            catch (Exception ex) 
            {
                objModel.ErrorMessage = "Unidentified Error";
                objModel.ErrorCode = 500;
                objModel.UserGuid = Convert.ToString(user.UserGuid);
            }
            return objModel;
        }
        else
        {
            objModel.ErrorMessage = "Invalid/Incomplete requests";
            objModel.ErrorCode = 400;

            return objModel;
        }
    }
```

And the model for the above method is:

```
 public class RemoveAccountModel
{
    public User User { get; set; }

}

public class RemoveAccountRes
{
    public int ErrorCode { get; set; }
    public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserGuid { get; set; }
    public bool Success { get; set; }
}
```

I have created a separate Test project to test this api method.
Following is the ajax call which gets invoked on click of Delete button:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#btnDelete").click(function () {
                alert("Hello");
                var request = $.ajax({
                    url: "http://localhost:13979/api/RemoveAccount?function='delete'",
                    type: "DELETE",
                    dataType: "json"
                });

                request.done(function (msg) {
                    alert("Request success: " + msg);
                    $("#divResponse").empty().append("<span>" + JSON.stringify(msg) + "</span>");
                    //console.log(JSON.stringify(msg));
                });

                request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
                    alert("Request failed: " + textStatus);
                    $("#divResponse").empty().append("<span>" + JSON.stringify(textStatus) + "</span>");
                    //console.log(JSON.stringify(textStatus));
                });


            });

        });
```

When I tried to debug, I found that its not calling that URL and am getting "Internal Server Error" only for this method, rest all are working fine.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Can you give some details about that error? Using Developer Tools in browser or Fiddler could give us a bit more details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you already have the parameter `function=delete` does it really matter if the type of HTTP request is `DELETE`, I would recommend changing it to `POST`

from  [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/):

> The type of request to make ("POST" or "GET"), default is "GET". Note: Other HTTP request methods, such as PUT and DELETE, can also be used here, but they are not supported by all browsers.

another thing ... Do you have this mapped properly?

`http://localhost:13979/api/RemoveAccount` is calling a function called `Delete` - which is fine  if you handle that in your routing code.

Comment: Hi. Thanks. I changed HTTP request to POST and now it works correctly. :)